Movie about glasses that can take you to a world of imagination
Ok, for this movie I don't remember much, but at the start, a group of guys stole something and is being chased by cops, they running wild, jumping all over the place the cops is shooting them, I think the one guy jumps and falls, then he wakes up in the real world, taking the glasses off, saying wow, this is amazing, so pretty much, you can live in your own world and be who you want and do what you want when you wearing those glasses, I think the guy who invented it, wife is dead, so he uses the glasses to be with his wife, of was that scene one guy who wanted to be with a women?, its expensive to use the glasses, and people are after him to get there hands on it, English language, Hollywood movie, that's about all I remember?

Sounds a bit like "Strange Days" -- which is about equipment you put on your head that lets you experience a scene from the life of someone else who recorded the scene while living it. 
The movie opens with a robbery that leads to a police chase, which is recorded and then "enjoyed" by a user of the technology. The technology is illegal and is sold on the black market by dealers, as if it were an illegal drug. 
The main character misses his ex-girlfriend and uses the device to re-live moments with her. 
Trailer here

Sounds reasonable. Always waited for a question about this amazing movie (though not for an ID question).

This sounds similar to Brainstorm
